# TYPO3: new fields in TCEforms for localized pages

Tags: typo3, backend

I know how to add fields to the pages table and placing them wherever I want in the TCEforms using the function addToAllTCAtypes(), no problem with that. However, the fields only appear for the pages in the default language, they don't in localized pages. Is there a way to make the added fields visible for any language?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in `$TCA['pages']['ctrl']['transForeignTable']` the table `pages` uses an extra table for its localization.

Your new fields need to exist in that overlay table `pages_language_overlay`. Also have a look at this tables TCA, that'll help you out.

Comment: Obviously, this was the reason. I extended the pages table, but not the pages_language_overlay table. Thanks a lot.